# Iterative test for positive semidefiniteness

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite

I have block matrices of the form $$\begin{pmatrix} A & v \\ v^T & x \end{pmatrix}$$ with scalar $x$ that need to be tested for positive semidefiniteness or positive definiteness.

[According to J.M.'s answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13282/determining-whether-a-symmetric-matrix-is-positive-definite-algorithm) the recommended way to do this is by Cholesky decomposition, assuming nothing else is known about the matrix. However in my situation I am guaranteed that $A$ is positive semidefinite resp. positive definite.

If $A$ is positive definite then I only need to test whether $x \ge v^T A^{-1} v.$ (Is this the fastest test?)

When $A$ is positive semidefinite, it is necessary to specify that $v \in \mathrm{im}(A)$ (and this is sufficient for $v$). I am not sure what a necessary and sufficient criterion for $x$ is. Hopefully it can be done without computing a Cholesky decomposition for $A$. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the entries of my matrix are integers. I don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: Is A sparse or dense?

Comment: @BrianBorchers $A$ is not sparse

Comment: The quickest way to compute $v^{T}A^{-1}v$ is most likely going to be by way of the Cholesky factorization of $A$.